# How to convert an object into nested object

Tags: javascript

How can I transform the following:

```
{ 
     Eldoret: "900",
     Nairobi: "1900" 
 }
```

into:

```
 [
        {
          y:"Eldoret",
          a: 900
         },
         {
          y:"Nairobi",
          a:1900
          }
    ]
```

using JavaScript. I've tried using the following snippet but it just picks on the last property

```
for(var key in data3){
    if(data3.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        data_obj.y =  key;
        data_obj.a =  data3[key];
    }
```

**Output**:

```
 { 
      y: "Nairobi",
      a: "1900" 
 }
```

Comment: Each time you create `data_obj`, push it onto an array.

Comment: What you have a is simply an object. It has nothing to do with JSON. JSON is **data format**, much like XML or CSV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You iterate over your keys:

```
var myobj = { .... };
var objKeys = Object.keys(myobj);
var reformatted = objKeys.map(function(key) {
  return {
    x: key,
    y: myobj[key]
  };
});
```

Comment: This worked efficiently. Just had put the right variables and it did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

You can build up the result step-by-step by appending items to a new array in your loop:

```
data3 = {
  Eldoret: "900",
  Nairobi: "1900"
}

res = []
for (var key in data3) {
  res.push({
    y: key,
    a: data3[key],
  })
}

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Jochen i tried your solution and i was not unpleased.